# How do I plot only positive values of a .dat file in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a '.dat' file in matplotlib that has a data value column and a time value column. How can I plot only positive values of the data column, or how could I plot the absolute value of each data point.

Edit: I was able to plot the positive envelope of the data using scipy.signal.find_peaks and setting the height=0

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have a list ```val = [1, -2, 3, 33, -333]```, would you be able to obtain just the positive values, ```[1, 3, 33]```?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up using scipy.signal.find_peaks and set the height=0 to plot the upper envelope of my data

Answer (score 0):

to get absolute value you can use `abs`

```
abs(-28) = 28
```

to get only positive from list:

```
def pos(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x > 0] or None
```